# jMonkeyEngine 3.1 apk not installed

Tags: java, android, jmonkeyengine

I have a lot of problems with running jME project on android. Firs problem: jME SDK does not support latest version of Android SDK (it does not have sdk/tools/ant folder). I have found an older SDK version, but still it not working. jME creates MyGame-debug-unaligned.apk and MyGame-release-unsigned.apk, but both of them can't be installed on Android device (App not installed message). If I try to run app directly from jME SDK this i got in log:

```
C:\Users\Bublik\GoogleDrive\jMEprojects\Fuck\nbproject\mobile-impl.xml:10: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:958: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:969: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:312: 
java.lang.InternalError: Could not obtain X500Principal access
    at sun.security.x509.X500Name.<clinit>(X500Name.java:1399)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.writeSignatureBlock(SignedJarBuilder.java:384)
```